# How to prevent the TrayIcon popup to occupy the whole dispatcher thread

Tags: java, windows, swing, system-tray

I have a java application that uses a `JFrame` as well as a `TrayIcon` and I added a `PopupMenu` to the `TrayIcon`.

When I click on the `TrayIcon` the popup menu shows up, but the main frame freezes as long as the `PopupMenu` is visible.

My first thought was that the event dispatch thread is occupied by someone. So
I wrote a small example application that uses a swing worker and a progress bar.

```
public class TrayIconTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TrayIconTest");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    JProgressBar jProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
    BoundedRangeModel boundedRangeModel = jProgressBar.getModel();
    contentPane.add(jProgressBar);

    boundedRangeModel.setMinimum(0);
    boundedRangeModel.setMaximum(100);

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    TrayIcon trayIcon =
            new TrayIcon(new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB), "TEST");


    // Create a popup menu components
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
    popup.add(aboutItem);
    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    tray.add(trayIcon);

    IndeterminateSwingWorker indeterminateSwingWorker = new IndeterminateSwingWorker(boundedRangeModel);
    indeterminateSwingWorker.execute();


    frame.setSize(640, 80);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}

class IndeterminateSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

  private BoundedRangeModel boundedRangeModel;

  public IndeterminateSwingWorker(BoundedRangeModel boundedRangeModel) {
    this.boundedRangeModel = boundedRangeModel;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long runtime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    while (true) {
      i++;
      i %= boundedRangeModel.getMaximum();

      publish(i);
      Thread.sleep(20);

      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if ((now - start) > runtime) {
        break;
      }

      System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
    for (Integer chunk : chunks) {
      boundedRangeModel.setValue(chunk);
    }
  }
}
```

**How to reproduce**

When you start the example application you will see a frame with a progress bar. A `SwingWorker` simulates a progress action.

The `SwingWorker` publishes the progress value and also prints it to `System.out`.

When I click on the tray icon ('the black one') the progress bar freezes and the popup menu shows up. I can see that the SwingWorker is still running in the background, because it outputs the progress value to the command line.

**Investigation**

So I took a look at the application using `jvisualvm` and it shows me that the event dispatcher thread is very busy as long as the popup is visible.

[image: jvisualvm analysis]

I could figure out that look at the popup is made visible by the method `sun.awt.windows.WTrayIconPeer.showPopupMenu(int, int)`.

This method submits a runnable using `EventQueue.invokeLater` to the event dispatch thread. In this runnable the method `sun.awt.windows.WPopupMenuPeer._show` is invoked. This method is `native` and **it seems that it implements a busy wait loop so that the event dispatch thread is completely occupied** by this method.
Thus other ui related tasks are not executed as long as the popup menu is visible.

Does anyone know a workaround that keeps the event dispatch thread responsive while a `TrayIcon` popup is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using a `JPopupMenu` as workaround, but you can't add the `JPopupMenu` directly to the `TrayIcon`.

The trick is to write a `MouseListener`

```
public class JPopupMenuMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

  private JPopupMenu popupMenu;

  public JPopupMenuMouseAdapter(JPopupMenu popupMenu) {
    this.popupMenu = popupMenu;
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    maybeShowPopup(e);
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    maybeShowPopup(e);
  }

  private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
      Dimension size = popupMenu.getPreferredSize();
      popupMenu.setLocation(e.getX() - size.width, e.getY() - size.height);
      popupMenu.setInvoker(popupMenu);
      popupMenu.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
```

and connect it to the `TrayIcon`

```
TrayIcon trayIcon = ...;
JPopupMenu popupMenu = ...;

JPopupMenuMouseAdapter jPopupMenuMouseAdapter = new JPopupMenuMouseAdapter(popupMenu);
trayIcon.addMouseListener(jPopupMenuMouseAdapter);
```